# VBA Copy data from a selected row then paste it on a different worksheet, on specific columns

Tags: vba

what I would like to achieve is to copy the data from specific columns on selection, and have it paste on specific column of a different worksheet via command button.

Example:

I have selected range ("A2:K2") from worksheet ("ND"), and I would like to copy the data from (A2, B2, D2, E2, and H2), and paste it to worksheet("EC") on ranges (A2, C2, B2, E2, and G2), respectively.

Any answer would is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code below:

```
Sub test2()
   Dim rn As Integer
   rn = Selection.Row
   With Worksheets("EC")
   .Cells(rn, "A").Value = Worksheets("ND").Cells(rn, "A").Value
   .Cells(rn, "C").Value = Worksheets("ND").Cells(rn, "B").Value
   .Cells(rn, "B").Value = Worksheets("ND").Cells(rn, "D").Value
   .Cells(rn, "E").Value = Worksheets("ND").Cells(rn, "E").Value
   .Cells(rn, "G").Value = Worksheets("ND").Cells(rn, "H").Value
   End With

End Sub
```

Second question:

```
  Sub test2()
    Dim rn As Integer
    rn = Selection.Row
    Dim targetRow As Integer
    targetRow = 1

    Do Until IsEmpty(Worksheets("EC").Cells(targetRow, 1).Value)
     targetRow = targetRow + 1
    Loop

    With Worksheets("EC")
   .Cells(targetRow, "A").Value = Worksheets("ND").Cells(rn, "A").Value
   .Cells(targetRow, "C").Value = Worksheets("ND").Cells(rn, "B").Value
   .Cells(targetRow, "B").Value = Worksheets("ND").Cells(rn, "D").Value
   .Cells(targetRow, "E").Value = Worksheets("ND").Cells(rn, "E").Value
   .Cells(targetRow, "G").Value = Worksheets("ND").Cells(rn, "H").Value
   End With

 End Sub
```

Comment: This one works perfectly, mate! Also, if it is not too much, I would like to ask: What code should be added on this one in order to transfer another set of data to Worksheet("EC"), on the next available row? I am thinking it has to do with the End(xlUp) code.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a typo in the target range or would you really like to switch `C2` and `B2` in "`EC`"?
Simplest answer for your arrangement is:

```
worksheets("EC").cells(2,1).Value = worksheets("ND").Cells(2,1).Value
```

and so on.

Hope that helps

EDIT

You have to look for the first empty row in the target sheet

```
dim targetRow as Integer
targetRow = 2

do until isEmpty(Worksheets("ND").Cells(targetRow,1).Value)
    targetRow = targetRow +1
Loop
```

until you find the empty row you add the new data.
Using Code from @simon-li you need to write:

```
  .Cells(targetRow, "A").Value = Worksheets("ND").Cells(rn, "A").Value
```

and so on

EDIT 2

with the additional code it should look like this (way up was my brainfart, checking the wrong sheet)

```
Sub test2()
   Dim rn As Integer
   rn = Selection.Row
   dim targetRow as Integer
   targetRow = 2

   do until isEmpty(Worksheets("EC").Cells(targetRow,1).Value)
       targetRow = targetRow +1
   Loop

   With Worksheets("EC")
   .Cells(targetRow, "A").Value = Worksheets("ND").Cells(rn, "A").Value
   .Cells(targetRow, "C").Value = Worksheets("ND").Cells(rn, "B").Value
   .Cells(targetRow, "B").Value = Worksheets("ND").Cells(rn, "D").Value
   .Cells(targetRow, "E").Value = Worksheets("ND").Cells(rn, "E").Value
   .Cells(targetRow, "G").Value = Worksheets("ND").Cells(rn, "H").Value
   End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @ochs.tobi danke fürs korrigieren, ich gelobe Besserung ^^

Comment: By the way, would you suggest me a code that I could add in order to have my next data to be transferred, be placed on the next row after the first transfer?

Comment: Thanks again mate, I've tried to add your additional codes but it seemed that i've done it wrong.

Comment: Well the first new code comes between @simon-li 's codeline 3 and 4.

I switched the sides. My bad! the target sheet is on the left, the source sheet on the right side

Comment: Thanks for that mate. But i get a Run-time error '1004', says that Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: btw, the error points to the code which you have edited, in reference to @simon-li

Comment: Have you tried the second edit? There was a big typo in the first one.
I tried the second code with Excel 2013 and it worked just fine.

Comment: All is working now, mate! Thanks for the help! I have forgot to edit the worksheet, silly me.

Comment: glad to here :)

Comment: in order to mark your question as answered, would you mind choosing one of the two answers given as "accepted" to finish the task?  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)